# SSIS Derived Column Issue

Tags: sql, ssis

I have some data in a column in a staging table that needs to be split into multiple columns on the destination table, but I keep getting an error when using a derived transformation. The data looks like this;

```
1 - xxx,xxxx,xxx,xxxxx,xxx
2 - xxxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxxxx
```

From the OLEDB source I have added a derived column and called it something and added as new column, I have then tried to add an expression `SUBSTRING( [column] , 1, FINDSTRING( [column] , ",",1 )-1 )`
and I keep getting the error;

```
Error at Load Stg data into Table [SSIS.Pipeline]: The "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[Insurer]" has a length that is not valid. The length must be between 0 and 4000.

Error at Load Stg data into Table [Derived Column [207]]: Failed to set the type of Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[Insurer] to type: "DT_WSTR", length: 6000, precision: 0, scale: 0, codepage: 0.

Error at Load Stg data into Table [Derived Column [207]]: Failed to set property "Expression" on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[Insurer]".



------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0204006 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)
```

I have tried to use the advanced editor to change the column length, data type and still getting the error.
Each row of data has different lengths so I can't hardcode the length of each part of the data in the column. I am using VS 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What's wrong here?

Given the setup, the derived column task was able to correctly infer the initial length & type DT_WSTR 26.

However, the error message you provided indicates you have data that does not conform to that expectation

> DT_WSTR", length: 6000

A string in SSIS has a maximum length of 4000 characters. If you need to have a string that is more than that in a data flow, it will be brought in a stream/large object type (DT_NTEXT)

What you provided works so the problem is in your actual data.

### Source

A simple query to inject your sample data into the stream.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
    VALUES
        ('1 - xxx,xxxx,xxx,xxxxx,xxx')
    ,   ('2 - xxxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxxxx')
)D(mycolumn)
```

### DER Split first

The expression as provided (with `column` renamed as `mycolumn` in step 1)

```
SUBSTRING(mycolumn,1,FINDSTRING(mycolumn,",",1) - 1)
```

### Results

The data from the start to the first comma, right end point not inclusive

[image]

Comment: So potentially the data length in the table could be the issue here?

Comment: That would be my assumption based on the error message and the fact the simplified example shows you have the correct syntax for shredding your string. If truncation is acceptable, you could take the right 4000 characters `RIGHT(SUBSTRING(mycolumn,1,FINDSTRING(mycolumn,",",1) - 1), 4000)`